# Gerund or infinitive?

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

> The only way to find the Secret Room is **solving** x.

Is this sentence incorrect? Can we use the gerund here? I assume we can because if we reverse it, it'll be correct (Solving x is the only way to find the Secret Room.).

Comment: I'd probably include a preposition with the gerund version *The only way is **by** solving X*

Comment: Asking "is this correct" is off-topic here as it is considered proofreading. You should be able to research this quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

> The only way to find the Secret Room is solving x.

is grammatically valid (for reasonable values of x). However, a form using an infinitive is probably more common:

> The only way to find the Secret Room is to solve x.

the two have pretty much the same meaning.

Comment: I think if you're using the -ing form it would be more natural to say "The only way to find the Secret Room is **by** solving x." But I agree the infinitive is more natural.

Comment: It's more natural because it mirrors the use of the infinitive "to find". If the sentence started, "The only way of finding the Secret Room ...", then the gerund would sound better.